# How do Update selected users in PnP PeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, office-ui-fabric-react

In my spfx react component I have a DropDown field for selecting department and a PeoplePicker control for selecting  the responsible employee.
Each time department is changed (the dropbox), the PeoplePicker should be updated with a default responsible (retrieved from a SharePoint list) for that department.

How do set selected users in the PeoplePicker, when department is changed?

Comment: If you are using Fluent UI/Office fabric PeoplePicker control, you have to set `selectedItems` property of PeoplePicker control with users collected from SharePoint list. Check this example where `selectedItems={this.state.currentSelectedItems}` is set: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input @GaneshSanap

I wanted to avoid the Fluent UI PeoplePicker as it doesn't have buildin user search as the PnP PeoplePicker.

Also I'm using React Hook Forms (RHF) for state management and can't get any of the PeoplePickers registered with RHF.

I've tried to follow this https://spblog.net/post/2021/04/13/how-to-use-react-hook-form-together-with-fluent-ui-react-aka-office-ui-fabric-react

My workaround: Fluent UI PeoplePicker with a combo of useState and RHF StateManagement 

To improve this. How do I register a PeoplePicker with RHF StateManagement?